# DD-WRT mini: How to disable remote access?

Tags: security, router, dd-wrt

I would like to completely disable remote access to the router from the Internet and Wi-Fi.
I want it to be configurable only over LAN. What is the simplest way to do that? The router is running DD-WRT mini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default WiFi and LAN are bridged together and you can't disable one and keep another open